# HTTP request whose headers can be controlled and is automatically decompressed

Tags: c#, http, encoding, http-headers, compression

I'm trying to send HTTP requests in C# that look like HTTP requests from a certain software. I wanted to use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` but it doesn't give me the control I need over its headers: their letter-casing can't be changed (e.g. I want the `Connection` header to be `keep-alive` and not `Keep-Alive`), I don't have full control over the headers ordering, etc.

I tried using `HttpClient` from [CodeScales](http://www.codescales.com/) library. Unfortunately, it doesn't decompress responses automatically (see `HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression`). I decompressed it myself with `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` and `DeflateStream`, but it didn't work when the response had the header [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).
`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestHeaders` seems to give more control over headers than `HttpWebRequest`, but still not enough.

How can it be done?

**Edit:** I know that HTTP accepts those headers as valid anyway, but I'm working with a server that validates the headers and refuses to respond if they're not exactly what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

To set some headers in the HTTPWebRequest class, you have to either use an attribute from the class (for example HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true), or you have to add the custom header to the request by calling the add method to the request headers.
Something important is that is you try to add the header (in a custom way) while it's already an attribute of the request, it'll send you an error.

```
    objRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "some data");
```

is incorrect. You'd rather say.

```
    objRequest.Accept = "some data";
```

In your case you can :

```
    objRequest.KeepAlive = true;
```

Don't worry to much for the letter-casing, it doesn't matter as far as you're sending the appropriate headers to the server.

Comment: see edit: I'm working with a server that validates the headers and refuses to respond if they're not exactly what it expects.

Comment: Your server will look at the content of the header, not the name of the header as far as it's the attribute of the request. Have you tested with the KeepAlive attribute?

Comment: I've tested it with fiddler. It works if the headers are the same as the ones created by the application I'm mimicking and doesn't otherwise, even if the only difference is in their order.

Comment: Hey, I found a great link for you to watch! [About HTTP Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). Field name are case insensitive, meaning that using Keep-Alive or keep-alive makes no difference.

Comment: By the way, the order in which headers are received makes no difference either.

Comment: Please reread my edit and my comments. The server I'm working with doesn't use HTTP properly. Either someone implemented HTTP by himself when he wrote it and (s)he didn't do a very good job, or they're using headers to make sure that the request wasn't sent by a bot like the one I'm writing. It wouldn't be the first server that does that.
And as I've told you, I tested it. The only difference was (and I retested it) in the headers.

Comment: What 'control' are you talking about in your initial question? What would you like to do, if not ordering headers (unnecessary), and put some headers in capital letters (unnecessary too)? Let me know I won't let you down until it's solved :D